# Properties of Operations problem

Tags: arithmetic

Please help I can't figure out this problem

Let Z  denote the set of integers:  { …, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, …}.  Define an operation  on Z by
 x  y = 2(x + y).

a.  Is Z closed under  ?  Explain. 
 b.  Is  associative?  Explain. 
 c.  Is there an identity?  Explain. 
 d.  Is there inverses?  Explain.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What are the definitions of closed, associative, identity, and inverse?

Answer (score 1):

a.  If $x,y\in Z$, then $xy=2(x+y)\in Z$, so it's closed.

b.  $2(2(x+y)+z)$ does not generally equal $2(x+2(y+z))$, so it's not associative.

c.  There is no $x$ such that, for all $y$, $2(x+y)=y$, so there's no identity.

d.  There are no inverses, because there is no identity.